# Como saber qual lista um objeto pertence?

Tags: java

Estou com um problema, que não estou conseguindo saber a qual lista um objeto pertence.
Tenho que fazer um jogo de truco em java, tenho a classe jogador, e cada jogador tem uma lista com as cartas (a carta é o objeto), porém o jogo tem 4 jogadores. O problema é que para processar a jogada preciso saber a qual jogador a carta jogada pertence. Tenho a lista baralho, que contém as cartas criadas no construtor, e dou elas ao jogador dentro do loop.

```
public class Jogador {
private int id;
private String nome;
private List<LabelCarta> mao;

public Jogador() {
    mao = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void fazerJogada() {

}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
public List<LabelCarta> getMao() {
    return mao;
}
public void setMao(List<LabelCarta> mao) {
    this.mao = mao;
}
```

## Classe que está rodando o jogo

Chamo esses dois métodos no construtor, após inicializar os demais componentes

```
private void gerarCartas() {
    for(int i = 1; i<=40;i++) {

        carta = new LabelCarta(i); //crio a carta pelo indice 

        baralho.add(carta); //adiciono ela ao baralho principal
    }

    Collections.shuffle(baralho);//embaralhar

}

private void adicionarCartas() {

    for(int player = 0; player<=4;player++) {
        jogador = new Jogador();// crio 4 jogadores pelo loop
        jogador.setNome("Jogador "+(player+1));

        for(int cartaJogador = 0; cartaJogador<=2;cartaJogador++ ) {

            jogador.getMao().add(baralho.get(cartaJogador)); //da carta ao 

            baralho.remove(cartaJogador); //depois de dar a carta ao jogador a removo do baralho principal
```

}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez isso possa te ajudar, não sabia o que pertencia ao objeto LabelCarta, então surgeri um exemplo de atributo, se não der certo comenta aí que a gente chega lá.

```
    List<Jogador> jogadorList = new ArrayList<>();  
    private void adicionarCartas() {

        for(int player = 0; player<=4;player++) {
            jogador = new Jogador();// crio 4 jogadores pelo loop
            jogador.setNome("Jogador "+(player+1));
            for(int cartaJogador = 0; cartaJogador<=2;cartaJogador++ ) {
                jogador.getMao().add(baralho.get(cartaJogador)); //da carta ao 

                baralho.remove(cartaJogador);
            }
        jogadorList.add(jogador);
        }
    }

    private void donoDaCarta(LabelCarta labelCarta) {
        for(Jogador j:jogadorList) {
            for(LabelCarta lc: j.getMao) {
                if(labelCarta.getAlgumAtributoUnico == lc.getAlgumAtributoUnico) {
                        System.out.println("O dono da carta passada no parametro é "+j.getNome());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Eu estou inscanciando o array vazio no construtor do jogador, não sei se precisa fazer isso de novo. Estou conseguindo adicionar as cartas à mao do jogador, verifiquei isso e está danco certo. O ponto é que existem 4 jogadores, cada um tem 3 cartas, e eu nao consigo saber a qual jogador pertence cada carta. Nao estou conseguindo pensar em uma maneira de descobrir isso

Comment: Tem como mostrar a classe Jogador e o array baralho pra ver se eu consigo visualizar sua dúvida

Comment: Porque aparentemente você está instanciando a classe jogador a cada vez que se cria um jogador é isso?se for isso, eu recomendo vc fazer arrylist ou um hashmap só para vincular a carta ao jogador. Diga se é isso q eu te ajudo.

Comment: Isso mesmo, vou colocar o código no post

Comment: Pronto, editei o post

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: Funcionou, era isso mesmo. Não sabia que existia esse tipo de for.
Muito obrigado!!!

Comment: ele é chamado de foreach, criado a partir do java 5, que também é o mesmo que for(int i = 0; i < jogadorList.size(); i++) {
}

Comment: por nada cara, é sempre bom ajudar